# JSON_EXTRACT is returning an array - how to get the value

Tags: mysql

I have the following to extract the userId from the Json field:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(userData, '$**.UserId') as UserId FROM userTable;
```

is returning [26933] but I am after just 26933.

An example Json record in the userData field:

```
{
   "users":{
      "user": {
            "UserId": 26933,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith"         
        }
    }
}
```

Have tried '$**[0].UserId' but also returns the array and not the value.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(userData, '$**.FirstName') as UserId FROM userTable;
```

returns

```
["John"]
```

How do I remove the brackets and quotes?

```
SELECT userData->>'$**.FirstName' as UserId FROM userTable;
```

but the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Of All Your Json stored in the Table has an error , Remove the comma after `"LastName": "Smith"`

here is the corrected json

```
{
   "users":{
      "user": {
            "UserId": 26933,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith"            
        }
    }
}
```

And To the answer of your question you can use the below

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(userData, '$.users.user.FirstName')) AS UserId from userTable
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. Did the job. Went with SELECT userData->> '$.users.user.FirstName' AS UserId from userTable

Comment: Having not used JSON_EXTRACT before I am interested to know why the path $** and the path $.users.user give different resulting formats. I thought * was simply a wildcard for the path.

Comment: @RGriffiths , You can use it, Both works same

Comment: But they don't $** gives [26933] but $.users.user gives 26933.

Comment: @RGriffiths, it is a wildcard and that's the reason why you'll get an array as result: because there's a wildcard there could be multiple results. At least, that's how I understood it.

Comment: That makes sense. A great help - thank you.